# How to create a crontab file for a program?

Tags: cron, python

I have a question. I have a project implemented on the brownie framework, the launch is only from the project folder, the script is called by the command `brownie run /script/create.py -- network rinkyb`.
I want to create a task that will call `brownie run /script/create.py -- network rinkyb` in the crontab of the clloe at a certain time interval. I can't create a task in crontab like
`* * * * * * brownie run /home/denis/project/scripts/create.py`
because I have an env file in the project folder.
I also don't have a variant like

```
SHELL=/home/.local/brownie
HOME=/home/denis/project/
* * * * * * * brownie run /scripts/create.py --network rinkyb
```

I get an error that the brownie command is not found

Comment: - In the project folder, run `which brownie`. You should then get the full path to the `brownie` executable.

Comment: - Another thing is that you've got too many * * * in your example. Read `man 5 crontab` for the full syntax info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
HOME=/home/denis/project/
* * * * * /home/.local/brownie run /scripts/create.py --network rinkyb
```

?

As it stands, you're trying to run brownie using brownie itself. Furthermore, brownie isn't a shell and cron won't work with arbitrary executables in the SHELL variable.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. You may want to add some explanation on _why_ you think the approach will solve the OPs problem.

Comment: Thank you, that helped